# SQL query in python

Tags: python, sql

I have the following query that is working fine until I have not included flagprocessed.
flagprocessed is "[tinyint]" in the SQL database. I am getting "pyodbc.Error: ('HY004', '[HY004] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid SQL data type (0) (SQLBindParameter)')" error. Tried using '0', "0" but the same error.

```
"SELECT FormType FROM [Database].[dbo].[TEST] WHERE Name=? AND flagprocessed=? ",
                    (tName,), (0,))
```

How should I pass value 0 in the above scenario.

Comment: Try `"(SELECT ... ", (tName, 0))`

Answer (score 2):

You should be passing a single tuple consisting of the two parameter values which you want to bind:

```
sql = "SELECT FormType FROM [Database].[dbo].[TEST] WHERE Name = ? AND flagprocessed = ?"
cursor.execute(sql, (tName, 0,))
```